# XAML Designer error: Cannot Locate Resource for Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, themes

I have created a custom control - a toggle button and have added it to the current project. When doing this, the `Themes/Generic.xaml` file was also created, which I updated to reference the control's resource dictionary. Everything works well at runtime, but when I add the toggle button to my control, I get the error `Cannot locate resource 'resources/customcontrols/togglebuttonresource.xaml'.`

I have added the toggle button's resource dictionary to the `Control.Resources` but that doesn't eliminate the error.  I tried adding the `Generic.xaml` dictionary instead, but that does nothing as well. The error still occurs and the toggle button does not show up in the designer.

**My Control**

```
<Controls:MetroContentControl
             x:Class="PATestGUI.AHPA.PAStatusAndControl.Views.PAStatusAndControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org" 
             xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:PATestGUI.Resources.CustomControls"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:PATestGUI.Resources"
             mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Calibri" BorderThickness="1">
    <Control.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style .../> <!-- other styles here -->
       <ResourceDictionary>
    </Control.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <cc:ToggleButtonOnOff />
    </Grid
```

**Error**

[image]

**How do I get rid of this designer error so that my toggle button shows up on the designer?**

**EDIT:**

This is my project structure. Everything is in a single project. The ToggleButtonOnOff is referenced in both the PAStatusAndControlView and the Generic.xaml.

[image: project structure]

This is `Generic.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/CustomControls/ToggleButtonResource.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**EDIT 2**

ToggleButtonOnOff.cs

```
public class ToggleButtonOnOff : ToggleButton
{
    static CornerRadius _defaultCornerRadius = new CornerRadius(12.0);
    static Brush _defaultOnBrush = Brushes.Green;
    static Brush _defaultOffBrush = Brushes.Red;

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff), new PropertyMetadata(_defaultCornerRadius));

    public Brush ColorOn
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorOnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorOnProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorOnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ColorOn), typeof(Brush), typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff), new PropertyMetadata(_defaultOnBrush));

    public Brush ColorOff
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorOffProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorOffProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorOffProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ColorOff), typeof(Brush), typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff), new PropertyMetadata(_defaultOffBrush));

    public double SwitchWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SwitchWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchWidthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SwitchWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SwitchWidth), typeof(double), typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));

    static ToggleButtonOnOff()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToggleButtonOnOff)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public ToggleButtonOnOff() { }
}
```

ToggleButtonResource.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PATestGUI.Resources.CustomControls">
    
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitch" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ToggleBtnBase" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding BordderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorOn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorOff, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ToggleBtnSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitch}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonOnOff}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonOnOff}">
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnBase}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--SWITCH-->
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnSwitch}" Height="{TemplateBinding SwitchWidth}" Width="{TemplateBinding SwitchWidth}" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Not everything is clear to me in your question. So You have a User Control, this ToggleButtonOnOff, that is in other project than your main project, right? And You have ToggleButtonResource.xaml that is a ResourceDictionary (I guess inside You have some styles for that ToggleButtonOnOff?) that is located where? In the Main project, in the same project as ToggleButtonOnOff or as a separate project?

Comment: They are all in the same project. I have edited the question to show the solution structure. It is actually a Custom Control, which automatically adds the Themes folder with the `Generic.xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the content of `ToggleButtonResource.xaml` directly to `Generic.xaml`, instead of adding it as merged dictionary, then the designer error disappears.

Adding a merged dictionary with those resources to `PAStatusAndControlView.Resources` is also not necessary.

**Generic.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PATestGUI.Resources.CustomControls">
    
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitch" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ToggleBtnBase" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding BordderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorOn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorOff, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ToggleBtnSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitch}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonOnOff}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonOnOff}">
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnBase}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--SWITCH-->
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnSwitch}" Height="{TemplateBinding SwitchWidth}" Width="{TemplateBinding SwitchWidth}" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: As usual, @Clemens, your answer is spot-on. Thank you!